# Is possible to set protected cookie to Electron JS app?

Tags: cookies, electron, protected

I have an Electron application and I use a webview to login google to use some functions of a website. Each user can login with him account and will have his functions. When they login, a cookie has ben set to keep the session. But when I logout from this user and login with another in my application, the cookie continues set. I try to use store to save al user cookies but when I try to set them again I've seen that there are a protected Cookie called "__Host-GAPS".

As I read all cookies starting with "__Host" and "__Secure" are protected and only can be initialized without domain. But I need the domain, because the original cookie has it, and if I don't put it, I lose the session. When I put the domain I receive this error: "Failed to parse cookie".

I also tried to create a session from partition, but the cookies never saves on this new session, always on the default session.

I create a new BrowserWindow setting the partition session on webPreferences.

Can anyone helps me? Which is the best way to separate the cookies of each user? How can I restore protected cookies?

Thank you

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70170436/334451

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. The best way to do this is to use partition in the webview. I use the next code:

```
<webview id="myWebview" style="height: 600px;" src="https://website.com"  partition="getPartition()"></webview>
```

Where getPartition() function returns 'perist:' + userToken.

Comment: Is this limitation documented anywhere? This is not mentioned at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/cookies#cookiessetdetails

Comment: How do you get from call to `getPartition()` to setting cookie with prefix `__HOST-`?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70170436/334451