# How to set session cookies with `__Host-` prefix in Electron?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, electron

I'm trying to run Electron in headless mode to fetch content on remote server which requires cookies with prefix `__Host-`. However, the old code used to run

```
    var cookie = {
            url: cookieurl,
            name: cookiename,
            value: cookievalue
    };
    win.webContents.session.cookies.set(cookie)
    .then(function(result)
    {
        loadUrl(win, indexUrl, output);
    })
    .catch(function(e)
    {
        throw Error("Failed to load cookie, e="+e);
    });
```

and this seems to work just fine as long as `cookiename` does not start with `__Host-`. When I try to set cookie with prefix `__Host-` I get following exception instead:

```
Error: Failed to parse cookie
```

However, this limitation is not documented at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/cookies

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65086328/334451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This detail is not documented in the official documentation at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/cookies but it's a logical result of other rules. Specifically the [`Set-Cookie` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) is defined to follow these rules:

> `<cookie-name>=<cookie-value>` 
> ... 
> **Note: Some `<cookie-name>` have a
> specific semantic:**
>
> `__Host-` prefix: 
> Cookies with
> names starting with `__Host-` must be set with the `secure` flag, must
> be from a secure page (HTTPS), must not have a `domain` specified (and
> therefore, are not sent to subdomains), and the path must be `/`. 
> ... 
> **Attributes** 
> ... 
> `Secure` Optional 
> Indicates that the cookie is sent to the server only
> when a request is made with the `https:` scheme (except on `localhost`),
> and therefore, is more resistant to man-in-the-middle attacks.
>
> Note: Do not assume that `Secure` prevents all access to sensitive
> information in cookies (session keys, login details, etc.). Cookies
> with this attribute can still be read/modified either with access to
> the client's hard disk or from JavaScript if the `HttpOnly` cookie
> attribute is not set.
>
> Insecure sites (http:) cannot set cookies with the `Secure` attribute
> (since Chrome 52 and Firefox 52). For Firefox, the https: requirements
> are ignored when the Secure attribute is set by localhost (since
> Firefox 75).

Specifically, you cannot set cookie with name starting with `__Host-` prefix without *also* specifying `secure`. As a result, setting cookie as described in the question fails. Unfortunately, the exception is just `Error: Failed to parse cookie` instead of `Error: cannot set cookie with "__Host-" prefix without also setting "secure" attribute`.

Following should work as expected:

```
    var cookie = {
            url: cookieurl,
            name: cookiename,
            value: cookievalue,
            secure: true,
            // httpOnly: true,
            // sameSite: "lax",
    };
    win.webContents.session.cookies.set(cookie)
    .then(function(result)
    {
        loadUrl(win, indexUrl, output);
    })
    .catch(function(e)
    {
        throw Error("Failed to load cookie, e="+e);
    });
```

The above example also has `httpOnly` and `sameSite` attributes in comments to work as a reminder that you probably want to consider these attributes, too.